# Send an email to admin when user login in PHP

Tags: php, email, session, authentication, http-headers

I have a problem in my script but I am not sure why it happens, may be due to sessions or HTTP headers. I want my login script in this way "When user logs in, an email should be sent to admin with user's information", so by excluding email section in following code, simply login works well, also I tested email section in separate file that works fine. But I don't why email is not sending  and page appears as white blank screen with following code.

```
session_start();
$errors = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit']) == "Login") {

    if(empty($_POST['username'])) { $errors[] = "Please enter Username! ";} 
    else { $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); }

    if(empty($_POST['password'])) { $errors[] = "Please enter Password! ";} 
    else { $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);}   

    if(empty($errors)) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = sha1('".$password."')");
         $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

        if($row) {  
            $_SESSION['user_login'] = true;
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['full_name'] = $row['full_name'];

            /*******************Send Email***************************/
            //Send user information to admin            
            $to = "xxx@XXX.com";
            $from = "XXX@xxx.com";

            //Get User Information
            $Full_Name = $row['full_name'];
            $Browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];          
            $User_IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            // If IP address exists
            // Get country (and City) via  api.hostip.info
            if (!empty($User_IP)) {
                $country=file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip='.$User_IP);
                list ($_country) = explode ("\n", $country);
                $_country = str_replace("Country: ", "", $_country);
            }                        

            $subject = $Full_Name. " logged in!";

            $message = '<html><body>';          
            $message .= '<table rules = "all" border="0" cellpadding="10">';
            $message .= "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td colspan='2'><strong>Dear Admin!</strong></td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td colspan='2'>A User <strong>" .$Full_Name. "</strong> logged in with following information! </td></tr>";                
            $message .= "<tr><td width='30%'><strong>Name ID:</strong> </td><td>" . $Full_Name  . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>IP Address:</strong> </td><td>" . $User_IP  . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Country:</strong> </td><td>" . $_country  . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Browser:</strong> </td><td>" . $Browser  . "</td></tr>";                       
            $message .= "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
            $message .= "</table>";             
            $message .= "</body></html>";   
            $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) or die("Error!");

            echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";

         } else {
            $errors[] = "Incorrect login, please try again!";
         }  
    }#Empty Errors

}#End Submit
```

Comment: probably because of `echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";` ?

Comment: Ok, but I think it should send email though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic debugging. Before you send the e-mail, add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Then run, work out the problem, then REMOVE THOSE TWO LINES once sorted.

Comment: Thanks, and yes it showed me problem of headers already sent.

Comment: Good stuff. Don't forget to remove those debugging lines once  you've fixed the problem - you don't want all and sundry to see other errors that may help them create issues for you.

Comment: Yes I do, but I forgot that I was working in production, I usually add error_reporting(0) in production. :)

Comment: `error_reporting(0)` means "do not display or log any errors". This is NOT a good thing as you need errors to show in error logs (otherwise how will you fix something a user encounters)? Set 'display_errors' to 'off' but leave error reporting to show fatals and warnings.